# Why Using Maclaurin series is giving me a different answer?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

$$\lim_{x \to\infty }\frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x^{2}}}{e^{x}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$
I have to proove this equation using Maclaurin expansion, which I know how to do.
However, my question is when looking at the numerator.It's equal to $e^{x}$ then divided by denominator is equal to 1, meaning RHS is not equal to LHS. 
My question is more of a technical then how to solve this,because I know how. Using both ways I get different answers for some reason.

****Edit***
$(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}=e$

and then outer bracelet: $e^x$

following the answers I got a little bit confused...
why $\lim_{x \to \infty } ((1+\frac{1}{x})^{x})^{constant}=e^{constant}$
but does not hold true for $\lim_{x \to \infty } ((1+\frac{1}{x})^{x})^{x}=e^{x} ?$

Comment: The numerator is not equal to $e^x$. Do you confuse it with $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/x)^x=e$?

Comment: "because I know how" seems a little dubious if you find a wrong answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust please read the post again. my question is more of technical, Iv'e rewritten the question so it is easier to understand.

Comment: @user6394019: your "edit" is too informal to have a usable meaning. This is the source of your mistake.

Comment: @infinitezero Yes, I dont understand why this is wrong?  because if the numerator is e then raising it to the power of x makes it e^x. Then reducing it with denominator I get 1 which is different than LHS

Comment: @infinitezero(a^x)^x=a^(x*x)

Comment: You can't let $x$ go to $\infty$ in the inner bracket while leaving it fixed in the outer bracket.  Read @YvesDaoust's answer again.

Comment: @saulspatz thank. I  think I undestand now.

Answer (score 1):

The Mclaurin series for $(1+t)^{1/t^2}$ is $e^{1/t-1/2+t/3}$, let $x=1/t$, then your limit becomes

$$L=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+t)^{1/t^2}}{e^{1/t}}= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} 
\frac{e^{1/t-1/2+t/3}}{e^{1/t}}=e^{-1/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are (probably) using

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y\right)^x}{e^x}.$$

This is not justified.

---

In blue, $\dfrac{(1+\frac1x)^{x^2}}{e^x}$ and in green $\dfrac{e^x}{e^x}$.

[image]

Comment: Why? isn't it like writing ((1+1/x)^x)^x? the inner bracelet is e and raising to the power of the outer is gicing me e^x